# Add A SearchBar to a uitableview confronts an error in filter process

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am following a tutorial about how to add a search-bar for  ui table view to my swift project ,I followed this link ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtiamBbL5QU and I am stuck in the half of code. In this line of my project

```
 self.countries.filter { (Country:String) -> Bool in
            <#code#>
        }
```

I have this Error 
`String' is not convertible to 'HistoryViewController.Country`
HistoryViewController is the name of my table view controller. and the only thing which is different in my project with tutorial is that I have an array called Countries which it includes rows of dictionaries. I am going to post my other parts of codes here

```
import UIKit

class HistoryViewController: UITableViewController , UISearchResultsUpdating {


    var searchController : UISearchController!
    var resultsController = UITableViewController()


    var myPlistArray: [String] = []

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 115 //or whatever you need
    }

    struct Country : Decodable {
        let flagEmoji, Abb, countryName, pName : String

        private enum CointryKeys : String, CodingKey { case flagEmoji, Abb, countryName, pName }
    }

    var countries = [Country]()

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        //Filter through currencies

        self.countries.filter { (Country:String) -> Bool in
            <#code#>
        }

        // Update the results Table View

    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Curr", withExtension: "plist")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)


        do {

            countries = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            // Handle error
            print(error)
        }
        print(countries)
        print("countries.count:", countries.count)


    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return countries.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("hiiii")

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellforHistory

        // Configure the cell...


        cell.lblCellHistory.text = countries[indexPath.row].countryName
        cell.lblEmoji.text = countries[indexPath.row].flagEmoji
        cell.lblCurrencyName.text = countries[indexPath.row].pName

        return cell
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `filter` closure as below because `countries` is an array of `Country` but you are treating it as `String`(by doing `Country: String`) ,

```
 self.countries.filter { country -> Bool in
      return country.countryName == "Pakistan"
 }
```

or

```
 self.countries.filter { (country: Country) -> Bool in
      return country.countryName == "Pakistan"
 }
```

Or simply,

```
self.countries.filter { $0.countryName == "Pakistan" }
```

**Edit**

To get the list of country `names` (i.e, `[String]`), you have to use `map` on filtered result as below,

```
let filteredCountryNames = self.countries.filter { (country: Country) -> Bool in
          return country.countryName == "Pakistan"
     }.map { $0.countryName }
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems It works, but let me check it more. Thank you very very much

Comment: I would recommend using `country.countryName.contains(searchTerm)`

Comment: It seems it works fine but I found a new error, I defined an array like this now `var filteredCountries = [String]()` and then I assigned like this `self.filteredCountries = self.countries.filter { (Country) -> Bool in
            
            return true`  and again it has an error `Cannot assign value of type '[HistoryViewController.Country]' to type '[String]'`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix it or should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: @Scriptable Seems great, would you please answer my question?

Comment: Excuse me but I just wanna ask you to help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186189/adding-a-searchbar-to-uitableview-throw-an-exception problem if it possible please. I really really appreciate your time.

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh Sorry i couldn't help on that as i was unable to find some time and the issue wasn't clear. If you still need any help, please share your code via `git` if possible so that it gets fixed quickly.

Comment: @Kamran Mr KAmran, Thank you very very much for your concern. it solved right now . thank you very much, I found the solution. but I will be happy to keep in touch with you for further projects.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a dictionary but an array of countries so your filter closure should look something like this

```
let result  = countries.filter { $0.countryName.starts(with: searchStr) }
```

or

```
let result  = countries.filter { $0.countryName == searchStr) }
```

Depending on how you want to filter. If you want to make the search case insensitive then call `lowercased()` for both the property and search string

```
let result  = countries.filter { $0.countryName.lowercased().starts(with: searchStr.lowercased()) }
```

Comment: bottom line wouldn't work, comparing a `Country` to `String`